# Awk generate new field

Tags: awk, midi

A MIDI Dataset show its timeline, Noteon/off, Chanelnumber, Pitch and Velocity.

```
0 On ch=1 n=64 v=65
240 On ch=1 n=76 v=68
318 On ch=1 n=80 v=68
397 On ch=1 n=83 v=68
480 Off ch=1 n=64 v=0
480 Off ch=1 n=76 v=0
480 Off ch=1 n=83 v=0
```

To find the delta time of the first field works fine

```
$ awk  '{print  $0-p}{p=$0}{print p }' sample

0
240
78
79
83
0
0
```

What I look out for is the difference of field $4 between "On n=x" and the next note "Off n=x". This would become field $6 to the note "On n=x" line. As example the deltatime ($1) of "0 On ch=1 n=64 v=65"  and "480 Off ch=1 n=64 v=0" gives the duration of n=64 "0 On ch=1 n=64 v=65 dur=480".

```
0 On ch=1 n=64 v=65
240 On ch=1 n=76 v=68
318 On ch=1 n=80 v=68
397 On ch=1 n=83 v=68
480 Off ch=1 n=64 v=0
480 Off ch=1 n=76 v=0
```

would become

```
0 On ch=1 n=64 v=65 dur=480
240 On ch=1 n=76 v=68 dur=240
318 On ch=1 n=80 v=68 dur=not clear yet because no Off in sight
397 On ch=1 n=83 v=68 dur=83
480 Off ch=1 n=64 v=0 dur=not clear yet because no Off in sight
480 Off ch=1 n=76 v=0 durf=not clear yet because no Off in sight
480 Off ch=1 n=83 v=0 dur=not clear yet because no Off in sight
```

Sample update

```
0 On ch=1 n=64 v=65
240 On ch=1 n=76 v=68
318 On ch=1 n=80 v=68
397 On ch=1 n=83 v=68
480 Off ch=1 n=64 v=0
480 Off ch=1 n=76 v=0
480 Off ch=1 n=83 v=0
480 On ch=1 n=66 v=88
481 Off ch=1 n=80 v=0
720 On ch=1 n=71 v=68
780 On ch=1 n=76 v=68
840 On ch=1 n=81 v=68
900 On ch=1 n=83 v=68
960 Off ch=1 n=66 v=0
960 Off ch=1 n=71 v=0
960 Off ch=1 n=76 v=0
960 Off ch=1 n=81 v=0
960 Off ch=1 n=83 v=0
960 On ch=1 n=59 v=69
```

would become

```
0 On ch=1 n=64 v=65 dur=480
240 On ch=1 n=76 v=68 dur=240
318 On ch=1 n=80 v=68 dur=163
397 On ch=1 n=83 v=68 dur=83
480 On ch=1 n=66 v=88 dur=480
720 On ch=1 n=71 v=68 dur=240
780 On ch=1 n=76 v=68 dur=180
840 On ch=1 n=81 v=68 dur=120
900 On ch=1 n=83 v=68 dur=160
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you'd want what you posted to be your expected output. Why report there's no duration yet since no "Off" has been see when the 2nd field **is** "Off" and you already reported the duration for that pitch?

So here's what I think you probably **really** want and if it's not then hopefully you can massage it to do what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    time  = $1
    state = $2
    pitch = $4
}
!seen[pitch]++ {
    preDur[++numPitches] = $0
    pitches[numPitches]  = pitch
}
{
    stateTime[pitch,state] = time
}
END {
    for (pitchNr=1; pitchNr<=numPitches; pitchNr++) {
        pitch = pitches[pitchNr]
        dur   = ( (pitch,"Off") in stateTime ? stateTime[pitch,"Off"] - stateTime[pitch,"On"] : "not clear yet because no Off in sight" )
        print preDur[pitchNr], "dur="dur
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
0 On ch=1 n=64 v=65 dur=480
240 On ch=1 n=76 v=68 dur=240
318 On ch=1 n=80 v=68 dur=not clear yet because no Off in sight
397 On ch=1 n=83 v=68 dur=83
```

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding, it seems the dataset was to small. In the end each "on" need its consecutive "off" with the deltatime aded on  the lineend. After that the "off-line" may be deleted. Your solution works in the right direction, thank you for that, but somehow are quite a bunch of on's missing?

Comment: Looks as expected to me for the sample input you provided and that's all I have to go on. if your sample input/output don't adequately cover your use cases then update your question so they do.